# Flutter - Implementing JSON getter for API

Tags: android, ios, json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement the API [found here](https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=crypto-coins-news&apiKey=d40a757cfb2e4dd99fc511a0cbf59098) into my `home_page.dart` found below using [this flutter learners project](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/) for JSON parsing. You can find the full code at [this GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Jak3-02/cryptick)

Looking at the current picture below, I would like the end project 'Trending News' section to return the article picture from the API, as well as the title instead of 'Item 1', 'Item 2' etc...

I'm having issues with this version, as when I try to run for debug I get the issue; `The getter length was called on null`

`home_page.dart`;

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:one/cryptoData/crypto_data.dart';
import 'package:one/modules/crypto_presenter.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'background.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=crypto-coins-news&apiKey=d40a757cfb2e4dd99fc511a0cbf59098');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that will convert a response body into a List<Photo>
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Photo {
  final int albumId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> implements CryptoListViewContract {
  CryptoListPresenter _presenter;
  List<Crypto> _currencies;
  bool _isLoading;
  final List<MaterialColor> _colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.indigo, Colors.red];

  final List<Photo> photos;

  _HomePageState() {
    _presenter = new CryptoListPresenter(this);
  }


    List<String> items = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 6",
    "Item 7",
    "Item 8"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    _presenter.loadCurrencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Crypto App",
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 22.5,
            ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF273A48),
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: _isLoading
            ? new Center(
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
        : _allWidget()
    );
  }

  Widget _allWidget() {
  final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
//CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED
   final headerList = new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        EdgeInsets padding = index == 0?const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0):const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0);

        return new Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('Card selected');
            },
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withAlpha(70),
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 10.0),
                      blurRadius: 15.0)
                ],
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new ExactAssetImage(
                      'assets/img_${index%items.length}.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
//                                    height: 200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: new Container(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: new Radius.circular(10.0),
                                bottomRight: new Radius.circular(10.0))),
                        height: 30.0,
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text(
                              '${items[index%items.length]}',
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: photos.length,
    );

      final body = new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: new Container(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,),
                        child: new Text(
                          "Trending News",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 0.8,
                            fontFamily: 'Kanit',
                            fontSize: 17.5,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                      ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                      height: 300.0, width: _width, child: headerList),
                  new Expanded(child:
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final int i = index;
                  final Crypto currency = _currencies[i];
                  final MaterialColor color = _colors[i % _colors.length];
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                height: 72.0,
                                width: 72.0,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      new BoxShadow(
                                          color:
                                          Colors.black.withAlpha(80),
                                          offset: const Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                          blurRadius: 15.0)
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                        new Radius.circular(35.0)),
                                    image: new DecorationImage(
                                      image: new ExactAssetImage(
                                        "cryptoiconsBlack/"+currency.symbol.toLowerCase()+"@2x.png",
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              new SizedBox(
                                width: 8.0,
                              ),
                              new Expanded(
                                  child: new Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Text(
                                        currency.name,
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14.0,
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      _getSubtitleText(currency.price_usd, currency.percent_change_1h),
                                    ],
                                  )),

                            ],
                          ),
                          new Divider(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

        return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
      ),
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CustomPaint(
            size: new Size(_width, _height),
            painter: new Background(),
          ),
          body,
        ],
      ),
    );



  }

// CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED


  Widget _getSubtitleText(String priceUSD, String percentageChange) {
    TextSpan priceTextWidget = new TextSpan(
        text: "\$$priceUSD\n", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black));
    String percentageChangeText = "1 hour: $percentageChange%";
    TextSpan percentageChangeTextWidget;

    if (double.parse(percentageChange) > 0) {
      percentageChangeTextWidget = new TextSpan(
          text: percentageChangeText,
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green));
    } else {
      percentageChangeTextWidget = new TextSpan(
          text: percentageChangeText, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
    }

    return new RichText(
        text: new TextSpan(
            children: [priceTextWidget, percentageChangeTextWidget]));
  }


  //DONT TOUCH, Works with cryptoListViewContract implimentation in _MyHomePageState
    @override
  void onLoadCryptoComplete(List<Crypto> items) {
    // TODO: implement onLoadCryptoComplete

    setState(() {
      _currencies = items;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onLoadCryptoError() {
    // TODO: implement onLoadCryptoError
  }

}
```

Last working version of the app;

[image]

Thanks, Jake

Comment: Did you try to debug your code with breakpoints?

Comment: Nah I don't know how they work so I never use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `photos` is null in your case. It is not initialized anywhere. I think you forgot to call `fetchPhotos()` method which returns `List<Photo>`. That's why null pointer exception occured.

Comment: Hey there Vinoth, could you please remodel your answer using the bounty notes provided. Thanks

Comment: can you post your full project? Because I'm not able to compile this class as there are 3 or so classes missing.

Comment: Okay sure, thanks for pursuing this and I’ll be able to post a github repo in around 5hr. Sorry for the wait

Comment: No problem @Jake. Waiting for your post then.

Comment: Okay great thanks. I’m out at the moment but I’ll get to it asap

Comment: Hey Vinoth here's a link to the GitHub repo, I'll also add it in the original question https://github.com/Jak3-02/cryptick

Comment: @Vineth Kumar just in case you didn't see the link, thought I should @ you just to be safe

Comment: Hi @Jake, I've completed the process. Where should i upload it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload this to a GitHub repo? It’s for a commercial project so I’ll let you know when to upload it so you can take it down after. That should be in about 30mins so please hold tight until then so you can receive your +50 rep. Thanks, Jake :)

Comment: Shall I share it via google drive? I'll remove it after u get it

Comment: Sorry I’m out atm didn’t get message. Can you please share it to jake.bailey8297@gmail.com. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179564/discussion-between-vinoth-kumar-and-jake).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing everywhere where you have

```
.length
```

to

```
(... ?.length ?? 0)
```

Like

```
itemCount: photos?.length ?? 0,

final MaterialColor color = _colors[i % (_colors?.length ?? 0)];

'assets/img_${index % (items?.length ?? 0)}.jpg'),

...
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could provide the code I left in the question above with all of this changed? I'm working on another aspect of my project at the moment and would like to keep my train of thought focused. Thanks

Comment: That's way too much code for me to go through. I'm working on another project entirly at the moment ... ;-)

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, when I get the time I'll have a work through it and let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: Hi Günter, just looking over the code and I'm noticing that `the final variable 'photos' must be initialised` under `_HomePageState() {` on line 60. What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: You might want to remove the `final` modifier and then leverage your fetch and parse methods in an initState() within the _HomePageState.

Comment: What would I need to add for this to work? I'm relatively new so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
class Photo {
  final int albumId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

with:

```
class Photo {
  final String albumId;
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as String,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```